# Is it possible to get EPOCH in Java in nanoseconds without using JNI/Native code or System.currentTimeMillis() * 1000000L?

Tags: java, epoch

I know this can be done in Linux, through a native call to `clock_gettime` from `sys/time.h`.

I know this can be done with `System.currentTimeMillis() * 1000000L`, which is not good because you can have two equal epoch times if you call that in succession.

Wondering if **in the more recent versions of Java** there is already a Java way of getting Epoch in nanoseconds.

NOTE: I want the epoch with nanosecond precision. I just **don't want** to convert it to milliseconds with something like:

```
long nanos = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toNanos(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Thanks for any help!

---

**EDIT1:** I'm not worried about getting the same epoch time twice. My goal is to have a real epoch time in nanoseconds.

Comment: Just in case you want to depend on the fact that two calls return different values: Don't. Even if a system can provide higher-than-millisecond resolution, there's absolutely no guarantee that two calls to whichever method provides this return different values. For example it's quite possible that a OS can return values with 1/10th millisecond resolution but not true nanosecond resolution.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Thanks for the warning.  My problem is actually precision, i need the nanosecond information. Returning the same time is not a problem. I should have been more clear about that.

Comment: I'm shocked that this question hasn't been closed and/or downgraded. Has anything changed in SO recently? Was it liberated from the [tyrannical mods](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IbDAmvUwo5c)? What happened to: _It has already been answered!_ _We don't do your homework!_ _Don't you know how to Google?_

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve with this comment. Are you complaining that you're not being treated unfairly enough?

Comment: To satiate your desire for perceived unfair interactions, I've closed this question as a duplicate with some very good answers that tell you both ways to achieve that and caveats to keep in mind (note: I didn't really do that for the lolz, I did it because the dupe actually fully answers what this is asking).

Comment: @JavaCoderUkraine Why the poor attitude?  Your question was up voted.  You were provided an answer.  Then you complain for not having your question closed.  Then you complain when it *is* closed.

Comment: Sorry but SO is irrelevant. It is only good as a read-only reference. For anything new we go to Reddit.

Answer (score 3):

This should work. Instant and other recent time improvements are from the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) package.

```
Instant t = Instant.now();
System.out.println(t.getEpochSecond()*1_000_000_000 + t.getNano());
```

prints something like

```
1682327653903147800
```

Of course, by the time `instant.now()` has returned, the time has certainly changed significantly from a `nanosecond` perspective.

Comment: Just to be clear to everyone: `System.nanoTime()` is **not** epoch

Comment: Sorry - my bad on the time

Comment: To elaborate on why `System.nanoTime` is not epoch: it returns the elapsed time in nanoseconds since an *arbitrary* instant (the *origin* time). [See the JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime()) for more details.